# Настройка ТВ тюнера belolder 507 в Ubuntu

Tags: тв-тюнер, ubuntu

Как настроить **ТВ тюнер belolder 507** в Ubuntu 10.11 и какую программу для просмотра ТВ посоветуете? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть устройство `/dev/video0`, то всё должно работать. Я всегда пользовался `tvtime` для просмотра и `lirc` для пульта.

Answer (score 0):

Я в своё время ставил программу, но у меня 609. Посмотрите здесь: [поддержка всех тюнеров Beholder в Linux](http://www.beholder.ru/bb/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5519&sid=0315a47a0ec9c82852e5b40f5d4514e4).